# Sublime Text regex find/replace within multiple html files

Tags: html, regex, twitter-bootstrap, sublimetext2

I'm using Sublime Text 2 for some find&replace operations. I'm looking for a regex that replaces only the h1 classes tags to bootstrap breadcrumbs, but doesn't affect the content inside them. Each h1 tag has a different text and as there're over 700 files, doing this manually is a hard work!

For example, i'd like to replace this:

```
<h1 class="xyz">SOME CONTENT</h1>
```

To this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> 
<li>
<a href="#">anylink</a>
</li>
<li>
<span>SOME CONTENT</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

That "SOME CONTENT" would be the text that I want to keep.

It is possible?

I'm using this code to find the tags and content:

```
<h1 class="xyz">[^<>]*</h1>
```

But if i replace to this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> 
<li>
<a href="#">anylink</a>
</li>
<li>
<span>[^<>]*</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

It replaces the text (which I want to keep) with the expression [^<>]*.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another example (I do not think it is necessary to include the closing `>`):

```
<h1 class="xyz">([^<]*)</h1>
```

The capturing group `([^<]*)` its saying *“Anything that is not a `<` zero to more times”*

And then you should use the captured group with `\1` or `$1`, (I do not know how it works on sublime)

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> 
   <li>
      <a href="#">anylink</a>
   </li>
   <li>
      <span>\1</span> <!-- or $1, the one sublime text uses -->
   </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you too much. Actually, it worked like a charm and with both (\1 or $1). Cheers, algui91.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve it like this :

**find using :**

```
<h1 class="xyz">([^<>]*)</h1>
```

**replace with :**

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> 
<li>
<a href="#">anylink</a>
</li>
<li>
<span>$1</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thank you, siam. The three answers are perfect. But as I saw and tested algui91's suggestion first, I voted up for him. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

In the search field, you'll need to capture the text you want in a group with brackets :

```
<h1 class="xyz">([^<>]*)</h1>
```

And in the replace field, use the captured group with `$1` like this :

```
<ol class="breadcrumb"> 
<li>
<a href="#">anylink</a>
</li>
<li>
<span>$1</span>
</li>
</ol>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, JazZ. The three answers are perfect. But as I saw and tested algui91's suggestion first, I voted up for him. Thank you anyway.